# Textbook request for class field theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, textbook-recommendation, class-field-theory

I am studying class field theory. I need good reference books, notes, or other materials which explain the following topics: ideles and ideals, Haar measure and integration on local fields, Fourier analysis on local fields, Fourier transform, multiplicative characters, and local zeta functions.

I know the book "Algebraic Number Theory" by Cassels and Fröhlich. I studied its chapter on global fields, and I know the definition and first few properties of adeles and ideles. Then I tried to read the chapter on Tate's thesis but I find it very difficult. Actually, I am not so good in analysis and I don't have a clear conception of the Haar measure.

It will be very helpful if someone suggests textbooks appropriate as an introduction to the subject of class field theory and where the above topics are well explained with all the details.

Comment: Duplicate?  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24719/suggestions-for-good-books-on-class-field-theory and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6932/learning-class-field-theory-local-or-global-first

Answer (score 3):

Ramakrishnan and Valenza's *Fourier Analysis on Number Fields* has all the topics you name, but doesn't prove the main theorems of class field theory. If you want a book which has all of this and also the class field theory proofs (but moves a lot faster) try Weil's *Basic Number Theory.*

Answer (score 2):

Ramakrishnan and Valenza, Fourier Analysis on Number Fields gives a gentle treatment of Tate's thesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try Deitmar and Echterhoff: Principles of Haromic Analysis. The second edition contains a chapter on adeles and ideles.