# How to prove local class field theory from global class field theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Historically (as I gather from [Learning Class Field Theory: Local or Global First?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6932/learning-class-field-theory-local-or-global-first)), global class field theory was proved first, and then used to deduce local class field theory. But nowadays most treatments do the local theory first.

Can someone give me a summary of how the global-to-local argument goes, or a reference to where the argument appears?

I'm interested in seeing this as a toy model for how to think about the current state of Langlands, where it's still the case that many local statements (e.g. local Langlands for $GL_n$) are proved via global methods.

I think these proofs start off by globalizing the local situation, getting a corresponding global object on the other side, and then extracting a local component. The issue is then showing that this construction doesn't depend on the globalization. Can you prove local class field theory along these lines?

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for but, if you use the $t^n$-torsion in the Carlitz module to get abelian extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$ ramified only at $t$, you get the Lubin-Tate formal group for $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the approach taken in Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory* Springer GTM 110. Lang develops global class field theory, and then in Chapter XI Section 4 he finishes "the proof of the complete splitting theorem and derives local class field theory, describing the effect of the Artin map on the local component $k_v^*$ for a fixed $v$."

Comment: Thanks! This certainly answers the question, though the proof is more "direct" than what I had in mind in my last paragraph.

Comment: @user125639 Sorry, I didn't mean this as an answer to the question in your last paragraph. I have no idea if or how this approach can be applied to the GL$_n$ case for $n\ge2$. I was just answering your initial request for a reference where the GL$_1$ argument appears.